# Разряды имён существительных

Tags: морфология

*Дело, ночь, день, личность дождь, гроза, ветер, форма, вечер* - к каким именам существительным по значению восходят данные слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы задаете столько вопросов по данной теме, поскольку пока не поняли главного основания разделения на рязряды по группе конкретность/отвлеченность/вещественность/собирательность. Это счетность.

**Конкретные** существительные имеют обычные формы единственного и множественного числа, их можно считать: одна корова, две коровы, три коровы; один аргумент, два аргумента, три аргумента.

**Отвлеченные** существительные означают несчетное понятие и имеют только единственное (смех, белизна) или множественное (хлопоты, выборы) число.

**Собирательные** существительные имеют только единственное число (редко только множественное), но обозначают множество счетных предметов: молодежь, старье, листва, аудиотехника. Иногда имеют соотносительные конкретные единичные существительные (студенчество - студент,  тряпье - тряпка), иногда не имеют (мебель, элита).

**Вещественные** существительные имеют только единственное число и обозначают вещество, которое нельзя разделить на отдельные единицы: вода, цемент, нефть, сталь. В отличие от отвлеченных, измеримы (литр молока, мешок цемента).

Если вы это все понимаете, то, очевидно, видите, что все эти слова - конкретные, они имеют обычные формы единственного и множественного числа. Небольшие сомнения в счетности имеет слово "ветер", но нужно вспомнить, что оно давно и прочно употребляется и во множественном числе: "на семи ветрах", "покорный всем ветрам", "южные ветры".